# Android camera app to get latitude & longitude without SIM or Wi-Fi (i.e. no internet)?

Tags: camera, geo-location, exif, android-app

Does anyone know of an Android camera app that is guaranteed to store Lat/Long in EXIF **regardless** of web/internet/WiFi, etc. connection?

Basically, all installed camera apps I have ever used need a network connection in order to include LatLong. e.g. Android 5, 7, and 9. And I have had web replies that clearly didn't read the "NO SIM" bit.

I use one phone purely as a GPS device for bespoke HTML5/JavaScript using Grid Refs & a database. Without SIM. It may be out of the range of cell towers.

If it matters, the device is Samsung Galaxy Note9 (SM-N960F).

P.S. I am currently looking at HTML/JavaScript code to get LatLong, but cameras are quick and catch the moment/location (approx even) when you ride as a passenger.